# Why is the ajax request not completed, but when I add an alert it gets through?

Tags: jquery, ajax, alert

I've been having a strange thoughts about this. Whenever I'm submitting my form and adding comment to the last alert part the ajax never executes but when I'm commenting it again it proceeds. Why is that?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.finalize').live('click', function () {
        $('#prodTbl tbody tr').each(function () {
            var epx = $(this).attr('id');
            var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
            arr.push({
                'idprod': epx,
                'qty': qty
            });
        });

        $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
            newArr.push([value.idprod, value.qty]);
        });

        var c = JSON.stringify(newArr);
        var dataString = 'arr=' + c;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/recordTrans",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });

        alert("1");
    });

});
```

If this one  is commented never does the ajax executes. Really strange or is it because of an error untrapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `.finalize` is a submit button, the page is getting submitted whenever you click on it because you are not stopping the page from submitting by returning false from the click event handler. Due to this the ajax call is getting aborted before it even completes the request.

When you have a alert the browser has enough time to make ajax request and be done with it.

Try this.

```
$('.finalize').live('click', function() {

    //Your code without alert

    return false;
});
```